# Routing absolute parth to a controler in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to rote absolute path to a controller bu I don't know how to do it; reason for doing this is to accomplish API post to that particular absolute URL;

`$route['duka/application/controllers/Forwarded_sms'] = 'Forwarded_sms';`

I have tied the code above but not working; I am still getting error 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

First of all create API Controller and use default controller then after use the absolute path..

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';

domain.com/duka/application/controllers/Forwarded_sms
```

if you have not created controller so please  put this controller code   and install rest libraries..

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');
class Api extends REST_Controller { 
    public function Forwarded_sms()
    {
        $response = array();
        $postData = $this->input->post();
        $this->response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response; but it is not working. my controller is "Forwarded_sms"

Comment: Please use this  domain.com/duka/application/Forwarded_sms and give me exact   url what are you using.

Comment: Hello; @noor alam, my API controller is Forwarded_sms and it is in local host now; what I want is to be able to assess it with absolute path without getting 403 error

Comment: ok you can use  this   localhost/derictoryname/cotroller/methodname    like use this  
    http://localhost/duka/index.php/api/Forwarded_sms  please check in postman

Comment: Hello noor alam and @Hritik Pandey; it will be easy for me to figure-out your solution if you will tell me what codes to put in CI routes and in my controller named Forwarded_sms; thanks.

Comment: Hello @MajiMazuri  I have updated the code please  check it let me know if you have any query.